# Android : Textview giving null pointer exception in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am having a fragment A in which i initialized another fragment say Frgament B. My fragment A is having a listview. On click of that listview i need to call a method of fragment B and update Textview. But as soon as i call this method it flashes following message in Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

My code is as follows :

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
// in oncreateview
FragmentB fb=new FragmentB();   

// on listview click item  i call a method of fragment B
setdata(value); // where value is clicked position

}

// Fragment B is as follows :

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
// IN ONCRAETEVIEW
initialized textview

return view;
public void setdata(int data)
{
// Updating textview settext method
}
}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the OnCreateView method

Comment: [http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-fragments-example-ui-multi-pane.html](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-fragments-example-ui-multi-pane.html)

Answer (score 0):

Only the fragment B is add into the layout then the View of the fragment B is created. So you should call setdata() after the fragment transaction.

```
Fragment fragmentB = new Fragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.layout.container, fragmentB).commit();
fragmentB.setData(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    FragmentManager m=getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentB fb=(FragmentB )m.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id_from_xmlsetdata);
            fb.setdata(value);


try with this code it will definitely works
```